# passing a jsonArray via url to mvc controller, cant get the object

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is my code from client side:

```
window.location.href = '/JQGrid/Export?fileName=' + excelFilename + '&gridModel=' + { gridModel: gridColumns };
```

gridModel is an jsonarray matches the properties of class GridColumn class.

My controller method:

```
public ActionResult Export(string fileName, List<GridColumn> gridModel)
```

On the server side, gridModel count is always 0. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: You cannot pass a collection of complex objects to GET method! (at least not without something like `&[0].Property1=value1&[0].Property2=value2&[1].Property1=value3&[1].Property1=value4` etc)

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting a list of GridColumn objects, but in your client side code, you're just sending a single instance, and not an array.

Comment: I dont get you. gridColumns I am passing is an array of GridColumn object.

Comment: I have even tried with public ActionResult Export(string fileName, GridColumn gridModel) I still get it as null...

Comment: What if you just take it as a string, and deserialize using NewtonSoft.Json or some other JSON library? I'm not sure, but it could be that you need to specify your GridModel as Serializable for it to work. How does your definition of GridModel look?